# Upload folder with files in it to existing repo

Tags: git

This thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57026164/how-to-upload-sub-folders-on-github) shows commands to do this. Particularly:

```
git add <folder name>
git commit -m "a commit message"
git push -u origin master
```

However, this only creates an empty folder in the git repo, without actually uploading the content of that folder (from local). This is the output when running those 3 lines:

```
[master 7e085c5] my commit message
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 160000 my folder
```

How do I just simply upload a folder with content onto an existing repo (under certain sub folder)? I am working on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Git does not store folders.  What you have is neither a folder nor a file: it's a *gitlink*, which is half of a submodule.  You can tell from this:

> ```
> mode 160000
> ```

The magic constant `160000` means *gitlink*.

What this means is that the folder you're trying to add files from is itself a *Git repository*.  Git refuses to store a Git repository inside a commit (for good but administrative reasons) and any attempt to do that results in the storage of the gitlink half of a submodule.  You, the programmer, are expected to understand this and to add the *other* half of the submodule yourself.

If you don't know what a submodule is, you probably don't want one.  Remember that a Git repository stores *commits*, not files; if you want to store *files*, not another Git repository, you'll want to extract the files *from* some commit *from* the *other Git repository*, put those into your own Git repository's working tree, and then add and commit those *files*.

A quick and dirty way to do that is to remove, recursively, the `.git` directory within the submodule.  **Remember that this completely destroys your repository.**  It leaves only the working tree files.  If that's OK—if this Git repository only exists because you cloned it from somewhere else, and getting rid of the *repository* while keeping the *checked out files* is the goal—then go ahead and do that.

If you *do* want submodules, **pay attention to the warning you got**.  Use `git submodule add` instead of attempting to add the other repository directly.